# How to save my location in a global variable

Tags: kotlin, android-gps

I am getting my GPS data via:

```
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                location2 = location
                var latitude =  location?.latitude
                var longitude = location?.longitude
                println(latitude)
                println(longitude)
                println("gps?")
                StopsFromWebservice().execute()
            }
```

which works.
But I want to use the location in a different method. So I tried defining

```
var location2 : Location? = null
```

and call it via

```
fun FindClosestStops(location: Location?){
    for (i in 0..haltestellen_lat.size-1){
        var x=0.0
        var y=0.0
        var distance = 0.0
        x= (haltestellen_lat[i]-location?.latitude!!)*(haltestellen_lat[i]-location?.latitude!!)
        y= (haltestellen_lon[i]-location?.longitude!!)*(haltestellen_lon[i]-location?.longitude!!)
        distance = sqrt(x+y)
        StopDistances[i]= distance

        Haltestellen.add(distance.toString())

        println("distance = " + distance)
        println("FindClosestStops")
    }
    SortDistance()
    time.post(UpdateView);
}
```

but then android Studio kills my task with this error:

```
Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.FindClosestStops(fahrplanmap.kt:100)
```

which is exactly this code:

```
 x= (haltestellen_lat[i]-location?.latitude!!)*(haltestellen_lat[i]-location?.latitude!!)
```

how can I write my location data in x and y?

Comment: Your biggest mistake is to rely on `lastLocation` which is almost always null when you  start an app for the first time. You must expect that and start a proper location listener and in there start your action that requires a location from `onLocationChanged` (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies). Also try to pass location and things as parameters e.g. `StopsFromWebservice().execute(location)` (see usage https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask assuming this is an async task)

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `location` as nullable and use nullable accessors to access `latitude` and `longitude`. However immediately after that you use the `non-nullable` operator `!!` which produces the error.

Simply said, you either need to check if `location` is null and define behavior if that is the case, or figure out a way to ensure that method is never called while `location` is null.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.
Sadly I am pretty new to kotlin at all, do you know how I can access my location in another function and store it in a variable?